# Is there a way to use ExoPlayer to recreate ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

`ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail()` uses `MediaMetadataRetriever` and that has a bug on the `finalize()` method that causes some crashes. So I'm wondering if I can instead use ExoPlayer to create my thumbnails?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the bug? What's the crash? What's the code you're using? What doesn't work with `ExoPlayer`?

Comment: The crash is `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.native_finalize(MediaMetadataRetriever.java)
       at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.finalize(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:332)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)`

Comment: I'm using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#extractThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int) and I have no issue with `ExoPlayer`, I'm not even using it yet.